# Page break for two detail bands

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I'm using page break in jasper report like this

```
        <break type="Page">
            <reportElement uuid="c4506272-8dc3-4456-b5c7-5098df455221" x="0" y="39" width="100" height="1">
                <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT} % 2 == 0]]></printWhenExpression>
            </reportElement>
        </break>
```

In my report, I have two detail band and I don't know how to put page break. Any kind help is appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to insert a page break in JasperReport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8069462/how-to-insert-a-page-break-in-jasperreport)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iReport subreport divided by a page break](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12491599/ireport-subreport-divided-by-a-page-break)